How could I achieve a "poke finger through paper" decal / whole (animated / sequence)?
I would like to make it so that a virtual finger can poke a hole through a paper-like surface.
It should not be a simple 1-image-decal, but it should be sequence of images or perhaps particles making this effect appear life-like where a crack occurs and then - as the finger pokes more through it - becomes larger over a certain time.
I am looking for realistically looking solution.
As I have not even found something like this on popular asset stores, I would like to ask how something like that could be achieved.
I would like to make it so that the hole in the paper slowly takes shape and is not simply "there" in the next moment.
Thank you for a suggestion how to make this happen.

You are probably searching for a stencil effect. https://discussions.unity.com/t/stencil-see-through-effect/782486 you would probably start with a small hole and increase it
